# How to change background color of firefox's inspect element

Tags: firefox, colors, background, inspect-element

Hopefully an easy one. I'm using Firefox 17.0.1 on Win 7. All was working fine, but now when i use "inspect element", the inspect element pane has a dark blue background with dark foreground colors for the html elements making it very hard to read. I have searched and searched but naturally most searches turn up results about changing a page's background color rather than that of the inspector itself. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer I have seen is to create a "user" style to force the background to be white.

Link: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/943857

To do this you install an addon for Firefox called "Stylish"

Link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

And use it to create a user style with the following code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url("chrome://browser/content/devtools/markup-view.xhtml") {
body { background: white !important }
}
```

I have done this and it works for me.

Link for documentaion for the Stylish addon:
http://userstyles.org/help/stylish_firefox

Comment: Nat: You are right on the money. I got a similar answer with a little more detail here:  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/943857#answer-387633  For anyone else, this will solve the problem very easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can change this, but you could use Firebug which still has a white background

Comment: Yes, but I find firebug a little unwieldly.